# Change toolbar menus in fragment

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I have `MainActivity` and it's have fragment. I added toolbar from `MainActivity`;

**MainActivity**

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When I was open any fragment from MainActivity then that fragment use own menu file

**In fragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

As you can see above I inflated custom menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu`. But It doesn't work.

Comment: I can't really see a question you're asking here

Comment: i dont want the show main menu items when inflate custom_menu items. So i use clear menu method but not working. So i show previously menu items

Answer (score 4):

after

```
toolbar.getMenu().clear();
```

add `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_blank);`
and I am not set toolbar as acionbar,Maybe you should user getActionbar to do something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're asking but I *think* you want to be able to change the options in the menu, dynamically. You can do the following

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    if (mHideSomething) {
        MenuItem myItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_something);
        myItem.setVisible(false);
    } //otherwise it will show as usual
    return true;
}
```

Then when you want to change something in the menu...

```
mHideSomething = true;
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

**EDIT** 

Now I understand you're just adding odd behaviour when overriding. You can still do the following (although it seems like these items just shouldn't be part of main menu if they're not relevant always)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    MenuItem mainMenuItemToRemove = menu.findItem(R.id.action_something);
    mainMenuItemToRemove .setVisible(false);
}
```

The only problem with the above is it makes assumptions about what is available in the main menu even though the fragment should be reusable. A better solution would be to pass in an interface to the fragment to call back to the activity and let the activity have control. Better still, update the activity logic and never inflate the main menu at all if not required.